# Как правильно установить Windows 7/10 на Macbook pro и зашифровать раздел Truecrypt/Veracrypt

Tags: windows, macbook

С этим большая сложность возникает, когда трукрипт требует 32кб перед виндой на диске

Answer (score 1):

Просто хочу чтобы этот мануал попал в поисковые системы, т.к. я промучался 7 дней пытаясь это осуществить, пролистал все форумы, нигде нет решения.

Через макось ставим нормальный iso винды на флеху с дровами

Ребутаемся в восстановление mac

Удаляем все разделы, вместе с macos и форматируем их в Fat

Запускаемся с созданной флешки

(важно) Создаем раздел на 300мб, затем раздел основной на 493гб. вместе с ним создастся системный на 100мб. порядок разделов должен быть: А. системный 100мб Б. 300мб В. основной 493гб.

форматируем 300мб и 493гб в ntfs

ставим винду

после перезагрузки получаем bsod с applessd.sys

грузимся с livecd (hiren например)

удаляем /windows/system32/drivers/applessd.sys

грузим винду снова и завершаем установку

винда работает, работают usb устройства (если нет читаем пункт 1)

bootcamp не ставится, вы думаете надо скачать нужную версию? нет, не нужно.

заходим на установочную флешку в bootcamp/drivers и вручную ставим все дрова.

удаляем по-одной папки из $WinPEDriver$ и жмем setup.exe в буткемп пока она не начнет устанавливаться

батарея не обнаружена? удаляйте все устройства батареи из диспетчера устройств и жмите обновить plug&play, получаете bsod, перезагрузка и все будет работать.

скачиваем truecrypt или veracrypt, они требуют чтобы перед системой было 32кб свободного места, решения в инете нету, но есть в пунктах 5. и 6.

ставим криптовальню и шифруем весь диск

всё готово, поздравляю, вы удалили macos, поставили windows и зашифровали весь хард.

да, 8 лет назад все было проще, но поскольку эплы решили обновить своё ПО, забыв подписать драйвера - приходится мучаться...